# Poor text visibility after ugrading to ubuntu 20.04

Tags: themes, 20.04, text

Here is screenshot of menu in status bar
[image: Menu Control]

And also in calendar and Notofication panel
[image: Menu Control]

I tried changing the theme from ubuntu's Yaru dark to Yaru light and also to Ant-Dracula (https://github.com/EliverLara/Ant-Dracula) but nothing seems to work.

I restarted my system also but its still the same.
How can i fix it?

Comment: Hey! Have you tried disabling GTK themes? Dark mode is now enabled by default, however, the calendar and power menu are not "dark-moded" yet, what makes me think you may be having trouble with GTK messing with the system's dark mode.

Comment: @Santiago I used gnome tweak tool to change theme to Ant Dracula. Is there another way i should be disabling gtk theme?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change different color profiles:

[image]

Then install

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweaks
```

After reboot, or maybe logout/login, you'll see in gnome-tweaks gnome-shell themes toggle:

[image]

After enabling that, you could change shell themes:

```
sudo apt install pop-gnome-shell-theme
```

[image]

Comment: I already tried changing themes from gnome tweak tool but it is still unchanged. Even tried Best RGB color profile.